# NSDateFormatter dateFromString on null Values

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter, unrecognized-selector

When I try to convert a string into a date using the `NSDateFormatter dateFromString` method, the app crashes on Null values.  I have found lots of answers and discussions on SO of when `dateFromString` returns null but can't find anything on how to handle a null value input.

The string in question is parsed from JSON coming from a server and is empty a fair amount of the time.  Following code works if date time has a value but crashes on null values saying: `NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x39ab2a70`

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *starttimestr = feedElement[@"starttime"];
NSLog(@"starttimestr%@",starttimestr);
NSDate *starttime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:starttimestr];
NSLog(@"starttime%@",starttime);
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Why don't you check to see if its null before trying to format it? I.e. only attempt the formatting code if you actually have a value

Comment: I tried various combinations of following but could not get any of them to work.   if (lasttouchedstr.length ==0), if (@lasttouchedstr), if lasttouchstr==nil) etc.  Can you suggest right way to test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check to see if `starttimestr` is really a string or not:

```
NSString *starttimestr = feedElement[@"starttime"];
if ([starttimestr isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSLog(@"starttimestr%@",starttimestr);
    NSDate *starttime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:starttimestr];
    NSLog(@"starttime%@",starttime);
} else {
    // starttimestr is either `nil` or something other than `NSString` (such as `NSNull`).
}
```